# Sitecore form DatePicker gives validation error in arabic version

Tags: sitecore-forms, datetimepicker

I am using `Sitecore 10.1` with the `JSS` React app, I faced wired behavior with Sitecore Form `DatePicker`. In English, it is working fine but in Arabic version gives me a validation error related to the date format

> The value '2023-03-01' is not valid for Value.

while this is the same format in English and working fine, I did not find out the reason for this issue, any ideas about the possible root causes for this behavior?

Comment: try to use dd/MM/yyyy format. What format you are currently using for this input?

Comment: This is the default format to render the datepicker, Because the property "DataFormat" in Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Models.Fields.DateViewModel (which is used to render the datepicker) looks so:
   "yyyy-MM-dd";

Comment: <Datepicker field={props.fields.date} format="YYYY-MM-DD" /> try to use this one. Because your format can be different according to client locale